# Adding numbers from Textfields with other numbers in Textfields

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Right now I have 3 Textfields where users can input numbers and I want to have all 3 textfields be added together and broadcasted into either another label or textfields later down the page. Is this something that can be done?

Right now I have the following for the 3 textfields

```
@IBOutlet var waistText1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var waistText2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var waistText3: UITextField!
```

and for the label where the data needs to go;

```
@IBOutlet var wavgText: UILabel!
```

My first idea was something like;

```
wavgText.text = waistText1 + waistText2 + waistText3;
```

Comment: wavgText.text = waistText1.text! + waistText2.text! + waistText3.text!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the textfields text as integer, add the values and convert back to string.

```
@IBOutlet var valueLabel: UILabel!

func updateValueLabel() {
    let number1 = Int(waistText1?.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let number2 = Int(waistText2?.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let number3 = Int(waistText3?.text ?? "") ?? 0
    valueLabel.text = String(number1 + number2 + number3)
}
```